# Jaxrs CXF Sping - @Context not getting initilized for Prototype scope beans

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf

My Application normally works, but I have problem accessing MessageContext. 
MessageContext is always null, irrespective of using @Context on instance variable or setter method.

Note: My interfaces are generated and cannot be changed. And I need new CarApiEntryPoint object for each call (i.e I want CarApiEntryPoint as prototype). If I remove aop:scoped-proxy, MessageContext gets populated but I get Singleton instance

In my beans.xml

```
     <jaxrs:server address="/rs">
      <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="carBean"/>
     </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
     </jaxrs:server>

     <bean id="cartBean" class ="com.xyz.CarApiEntryPoint" scope="prototype">
        <aop:scoped-proxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
     </bean>
```

Classes

```
     import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext;
     public class CarApiEntryPoint implements CarApi{
         @Context MessageContext messageContext;
         .......// Overriding methods from CarApi
     }


     @Path("/V1")
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     public interface CarApi  {
         @POST
         @Path("/cars/{carId}/")
         //methods....
     }
```

Please provide your valuable suggestions, on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I have used carBean only. Issue is still present.